# Tab options in blender

Tags: modeling

When I press tab I get this kind of menu, I dont know what I have changed, but i would like to go back to having all modes as options when pressing tab.
I dont want to go back to factory settings, since I have a lot of addons installed.
Thank you )
[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### disable the shortcut in keymap

search `tab` in Key-Binding
disable `view3d.object_mode_pie_or_toggle`

[image]